# how to change DatagridView Columns Headers?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

```
string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Harfosh.Properties.Settings.TYT"].ConnectionString;

//string strConnection = "ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Store_Manager.Properties.Settings.storemanagerConnectionString].Name;";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
con.Open();
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
sqlCmd.Connection = con;
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select rakmsanf ,esmsanf,esmmwrd,m5zn,quantity,w7da,reorder from Items  Where m5zn =N'" + comboBox2.Text + "' ";
SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
System.Data.DataTable dtRecord = new System.Data.DataTable();
sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
//  DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();


dataGridView1.DataSource = dtRecord;

if (dataGridView1.Columns[0] != null)
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Key";
if (dataGridView1.Columns[1] != null)
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Expire";
con.Close();
```

Now I get `rakmsanf,esmsanf,esmmwrd,m5zn,quantity,w7da,reorder AND key Expire`
I wanna change columns headers to `Key - Expire` and no need see  `rakmsanf ,esmsanf,esmmwrd,m5zn,quantity,w7da,reorder` (change Selected headers Name )

Comment: @Damith i am tried this but i wanna arabic names and i get errors

Comment: but i cant put spaces ex:-رقم الصنف 
get error But if i typ رقم only its works !

Comment: use brackets like   `[-رقم الصنف]`

Answer (score 0):

you can change the SQL as below

```
Select rakmsanf  as  [-رقم الصنف] ,esmsanf as Expire from Items  Where m5zn ='N'
```

then you don't need to do by the code

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Datagridview Column header in this ff. steps:

1. Right Click on the datagridview
2. Then select the column that you want to edit the header name, and on the properties, there is Header Text where you can edit the Header Name of your datagridview.

Hope it works.